# Why is it ok when your class doesn't has parameter-less constructor?

Tags: java

I have little confusion. As per theory if we specify any parameter constructor in class then compiler doesn't generate parameter-less construction.(That's why we get error in case of inheritance of such classes). Now suppose I have one such class

```
public class Response
{
    String gMessage;
    String gAvilableAmount;

    public Response( String gMessage,
        String gAvilableAmount )
    {
        super();
        this.gMessage = gMessage;
        this.gAvilableAmount = gAvilableAmount;
    }  
}
```

It has only one constructor, which has two parameters and its body calling super()(parameter less constructor, which is not available). Now I have one main method:

```
public class TesterMain
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Response lResponse = new Response( "dd", "dd" );
        System.out.println( lResponse );
    }
}
```

It works without any error.
My question is main is calling `new Response( "dd", "dd" )`, which again call to the two-parameter constructor of `Response`, which has first line `super()`(since class doesn't has any parameter-less constructor ), then how this call stack works?

Comment: super() calls the super-class parameterless constructor. The superclass is java.lang.Object, which has such a constructor. So, what's the problem? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html

Comment: I think you're confusing `super()` and `this()` - `super` calls the parent class's constructor, in this case Object's constructor because everything implicitly extends Object. Doing so here is unnecessary. `this` calls another constructor in the same class.

Comment: You should be more concerned by the fact that you call `super()` in a class that doesn't extends another class. To that you should also know that every class extends `Object` (that provide an empty constructor - or a default constructor, never checked which one...)

Comment: I don't understand why this was downvoted? The guy had a programming question and was trying to find the answer.. Let's not forget that we were also still learning the basics at some point of time.

Answer (score 2):

The `Object` class, in the `java.lang` package, sits at the top of the class hierarchy tree ([doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/objectclass.html))
So when you call `super()` in your class constructor, you call the `java.lang.Object` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You are confused with super() and this()

this(),this(param1,param2) - is the way we call in class constructors. For example

```
public Response(param1,param2)
{
    this(param1);
}

public Response(param1)
{

}
```

super(),super(param1) - is how you call your parent's constructors.

```
public class Response extends SuperResponse
{
     public Response(param1)
     {
         super(param1);
     }
}

public class SuperResponse
{
     public SuperResponse(param1)
     {
      }
```